# Understanding the relationship between the Iterator interface and the “foreach” statement

Tags: java, foreach

Why does implementing the Iterator interface allow an object to be the target of the “foreach” statement in java?

I mean what is the relationship between for-each and the [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface in java.

```
for(Object:Iterable<T>)
{
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that is the way the enhanced for statement is defined in [jls-14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).

Specifically:

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier =
        (TargetType) #i.next();
    Statement
}
```

Comment: can you explain more on it

Comment: @NiravsinhParmar What else do you want to know?  The "for-each" loop is just syntactic sugar for when you want to traverse an array or Iterable.  The [link in the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) on the Javadoc talks more about the rationale for providing it, if that's what you're after.  Basically, any time you don't need direct access to the Iterator, use for-each.

Comment: so it means that compiler take care of all this

Comment: @NiravsinhParmar Yes, it handles all of the actual iteration logic behind the scenes for you, so that you don't have to write it manually (and possibly make a mistake while doing so).  It has the added benefit of also making your code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

That's the JVM implementation, based on the language specs. For example, a Boolean is a target of if statement.

Comment: The JVM doesn't have much to do with it.

Comment: than what is real reason behind  this

Answer (score 0):

The words you used *Implementing Iterator interface allows an object to be the target of the “foreach” statement* sound like you already read the [Java Doc - Interface Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

So why didn't you follow the mentioned link to [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html)? A brilliant explanation is given there.